# Gparted live usb on XPS 13 9310 (developer edition)

Tags: boot, usb

I got an XPS 13 9310 with Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, it cannot load the Gparted live usb so that I can repartition it. I tried all the things I could find online: disabling the Secure Boot in BIOS, enabling Thunderbolt boot, disabling TMP 2.0. Nothing seems to help. When I press F12 on boot which is supposed to give me a list of bootable options I get an Assisted Support OS Recovery screen. There I do see two options with the name of my usb stick Kingston and Kingston 2 (is one of them efi and the other grub?). But when I select any of them there is just an error screen and nothing happens.

Note that the current XPS does not support Legacy Boot. Does Gparted need to be updated for this? I got the Gparted live usb image here:

https://gparted.org/liveusb.php

and wrote it on the usb manually with dd.

Does anyone know what to do and how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome, if you can run Ubuntu live, it has GParted.

Comment: You may have to also turn on full USB support or allow USB boot. Often separate from Secure Boot, but related as allowing USB boot is not Secure. Often have to update UEFI and if SSD, update SSD firmware. Dell is one of the few that can do that from Ubuntu. Is it this system with the new Xe graphics? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-xe-graphics&num=1